# react routing. cant get this to work

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react modules and classes,   I have User module, Users module, Add User module which adds a new user and The App container module for displaying users and static common file which has api urls. but the routing doesn't seem to work. any idea?

user.jsx - defines a user. it has its get, put, post, delete functions

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import PropTypes            from 'prop-types';
import axios                from 'axios';
var Base                    = require('../Statics.Common');

export default class User extends Component {
    static get propTypes() {
        return {
            user: PropTypes.object,
            getAllUsers: PropTypes.func
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.user = this.props.user;
        this.getAllUsers = this.props.getAllUsers;
    }

    update(id, name) {
        var updatedName = prompt("Please enter updated name:", name);
        axios.put(Base.API + '/' + id, {name: updatedName}).then(results => {
            if(results.status == 200) {
                this.getAllUsers();
            }
        })
    }

    delete(id) {
        axios.delete(Base.API + '/' + id).then(results => {
            if(results.status == 200) {
                this.getAllUsers();
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <tr>
            <td>{this.user._id || this.user.id}</td>
            <td>{this.user.name}</td>
            <button onClick={(e) => this.update(this.user._id || this.user.id, this.user.name)}>Update</button>&nbsp;
            <button onClick={(e) => this.delete(this.user._id || this.user.id)}>Delete</button>
        </tr>
    }
}

Users.jsx - users module renders list of users into a ui
 the
'use strict';
import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import PropTypes            from 'prop-types';
import User                 from './User.jsx';


export default class Users extends Component {
  static get propTypes() {
    return {
      users: PropTypes.array
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState(props)
  }

  render() {
    this.users = this.props.users;
    return <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            this.users.map(user => {
              return <User key={user._id || user.id} user={user} getAllUsers={() => this.props.getAllUsers()}/>
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>;
  }
}

AddUser.jsx - adding a new user

'use strict';

import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import PropTypes            from "prop-types";

export default class AddUser extends Component {
    static get propTypes() {
        return {
           addUser: PropTypes.func,
           name: PropTypes.string
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    onNameChange(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
       this.name = event.target.value;
    }

    onSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (this.name) {
           this.props.addUser({name: this.name});
           this.name = '';
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <form onSubmit={event => this.onSubmit(event)}>
               <label>Name:</label>
               <input type="text" onChange={event => this.onNameChange(event)}/>
               <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
        </div>;
    }
}

Appcontainer.jsx - the app container for displaying the class

'use strict';
import  React, {Component}   from 'react';
import Users                from './Modules/Users';
import AddUser              from './Controllers/AddUser';
import axios                from 'axios';

var Base = require('./Statics.Common');

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: []
        }
        this.getAllUsers();
    }

    getAllUsers() {
        axios.get(Base.API + '/').then(res => {
            this.setState({
                users: res.data.data || res.data
            });
        })
    }

    addUser(user) {
        axios.post(Base.API + '/', {name: user.name}).then(result => {
            if(result.status == 200) {
                this.getAllUsers();
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
           <h2>Users App</h2>
            <AddUser addUser={user => this.addUser(user)}/>
            <Users users={this.state.users} getAllUsers = {() => this.getAllUsers()}/>
        </div>;
    }
}

statics.common.jsx - this has some api urls for node and spring boot

var CommonDetails = function() {
    //this.API = 'http//localhost:8081'; // node api
    this.API = 'http://localhost:8084'; // springboot api
}

module.exports = new CommonDetails();
```

Comment: where are you doing routing here? there are no route tags or link tags, you are doing simple rendering. Your component is not wrapped in Router tag. What are you exactly asking?

Answer (score 0):

CONTROLLERS -> AddUser.jsx

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import PropTypes            from 'prop-types';
import User                 from './User.jsx';


export default class Users extends Component {
  static get propTypes() {
    return {
      users: PropTypes.array
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState(props)
  }

  render() {
    this.users = this.props.users;
    return <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            this.users.map(user => {
              return <User key={user._id || user.id} user={user} getAllUsers={() => this.props.getAllUsers()}/>
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

MODULES -> User.jsx

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import PropTypes            from 'prop-types';
import axios                from 'axios';
var Base                    = require('../Statics.Common');

export default class User extends Component {
    static get propTypes() {
        return {
            user: PropTypes.object,
            getAllUsers: PropTypes.func
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.user = this.props.user;
        this.getAllUsers = this.props.getAllUsers;
    }

    update(id, name) {
        var updatedName = prompt("Please enter updated name:", name);
        axios.put(Base.API + '/' + id, {name: updatedName}).then(results => {
            if(results.status == 200) {
                this.getAllUsers();
            }
        })
    }

    delete(id) {
        axios.delete(Base.API + '/' + id).then(results => {
            if(results.status == 200) {
                this.getAllUsers();
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <tr>
            <td>{this.user._id || this.user.id}</td>
            <td>{this.user.name}</td>
            <button onClick={(e) => this.update(this.user._id || this.user.id, this.user.name)}>Update</button>&nbsp;
            <button onClick={(e) => this.delete(this.user._id || this.user.id)}>Delete</button>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

MODULES -> Users.jsx

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import PropTypes            from 'prop-types';
import User                 from './User.jsx';


export default class Users extends Component {
  static get propTypes() {
    return {
      users: PropTypes.array
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState(props)
  }

  render() {
    this.users = this.props.users;
    return <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            this.users.map(user => {
              return <User key={user._id || user.id} user={user} getAllUsers={() => this.props.getAllUsers()}/>
            })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

APP.JSX

```
'use strict';
import React            from 'react';
import {render}         from 'react-dom';
import AppContainer     from './AppContainer.jsx';

render(<AppContainer/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

AppContainer.jsx

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component}   from 'react';
import Users                from './Modules/Users';
import AddUser              from './Controllers/AddUser';
import axios                from 'axios';

var Base                    = require('./Statics.Common');

export default class AppContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            users: []
        }
        this.getAllUsers();
    }

    getAllUsers() {
        axios.get(Base.API + '/').then(res => {
            this.setState({
                users: res.data.data || res.data
            });
        })
    }

    addUser(user) {
        axios.post(Base.API + '/', {name: user.name}).then(result => {
            if(result.status == 200) {
                this.getAllUsers();
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
           <h2>Users App</h2>
            <AddUser addUser={user => this.addUser(user)}/>
            <Users users={this.state.users} getAllUsers = {() => this.getAllUsers()}/>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Statics.Common.js

```
var CommonDetails = function() {
    //this.API = 'http//localhost:8081'; // node api
    this.API = 'http://localhost:8084'; // springboot api
}

module.exports = new CommonDetails();
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "app.jsx"),
    output: {
       path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
       filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
       rules: [
           {
               test: /\.jsx?$/,
               use: {
                   loader: "babel-loader",
                   options: {
                       presets: ["env", "es2015", "react"]
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
    },
    resolve: {
       extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    devServer: {
       contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "/"),
       compress: true
    },
    devtool: "source-map"
};
```

Comment: Please post only one answer. If you found a mistake in your answer, then edit it instead of posting a second one. Also, you might have noticed the comment on another answer that asks for explanations to go with the code.